# I used the wallet out of sync and cannot find my adress

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, address, wallet-recovery

This is the first time I am buying BTC, I used my bitcoin core wallet out of sync to generate and address and then I shut down the PC after the full sync has been made. Now I cannot find the address in the file anywhere. I still have the address and if I search it on blockchain.info it says that the payment has been made. Although, my wallet balance is zero. Can someone please explain how can I redeem my BTCs?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Core doesn't check if it's in sync with the network or not. Try using `rescan` to make the client go through all the blocks in the blockchain and find the transactions affecting your wallet.

Answer (score 0):

Open up Bitcoin Core.
At the top, click `help` and than `debug window`.
Go to the `console` tab, type `listaccounts` and hit enter.

It should return a list (in your case I guess a list with only one record), looking like the following:

`{ "":THE AMOUNT TRANSFERED }`

Please reply with the stuff you see when you ran `listaccounts`.